# How can I open new tabs next to my current tab, instead of at the end of the tab bar in Firefox 7?

Tags: firefox, tabbed-browsing

When I middle-click a link in Firefox, I would like the new tab to open adjacent to my current tab, not all the way at the end of the tab bar. How can I make this happen in Firefox 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option you can set.  Go to the address bar, and type `about:config`

After you click `Ok` on the warranty warning, do a search for this config setting, double click it to say `true`.

`browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent`

Comment: Huh. For some reason this was set to the non-default of False in my browser. I'm pretty sure I never set it that way. Setting it to true fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

7 years later.

Firefox version 63.0.3 (64bit).

`browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` is default `true` now.

And yet, to get [Ctrl+T], and the [+] button (to the right of the tabs), to open a new tab to the right of the current tab, instead of to the far right of all tabs, I set

`browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent` to `true` (by double-clicking this boolean preference).

It was default `false`.

I believe [Ctrl+click] and [right-click -> open in new tab] follow the behavior of the first-mentioned perference, `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent`, because they are "related" because you clicked on the current page to get to the new tab, and on the other hand [Ctrl+T] and [+] follow this new preference, `browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent`, becaused they are new (blank) tabs, and so unrelated to the current tab.

(Note one preference has `"Related"` in its name, and the other doesn't.)